# rewrite c expression without continue and break

Tags: c, break, continue

In a school exercise (on paper) i've this question:

5) rewrite the code without using continue and break:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    scanf("give me an int %d", & a);
    if (a < 0) {
        continue;
    }
    if (a == 0) {
        break;
    }
    /* elaborate positive int */
}
```

---

I'm thinking about this:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++){

 scanf("give me an int %d",&a");

 if(a==0){return -1; //??i dont know how to exit}
 if(a<0){
  do{
        scanf("give me an int %d",&a");
        if(a==0){return -1; //??i dont know how to exit}
    }while(!(a<0))
 }
 /* elaborate positive int */
}
```

but, I'm actually not able to do this.. can you help me? thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; i < N && a != 0; i++)
{
    scanf("give me an int %d",&a");
    if(a>0)
    { /*do stuff*/ }
}
if(a==0) i--; //As noted by Daniel Fischer
```

Comment: Lucian just theach me that i can use conditions in for parameters.. thanks!

Comment: Not quite the same, with the `break`, `i` is incremented once less.

Comment: This answer should be made a CW, I have implemented more suggestions than what I actually thought of myself !

Answer (score 2):

Might not be what your teacher wants but that's actually the easiest way:

```
a = INT_MAX;
for(i = 0; i < N && a != 0; i++) {
    scanf("give me an int %d", &a);
    if(a > 0) {
        /* elaborate positive int */
    }
}
```

The reason for not using `return` is that you just want to exit/restart the loop. The function *could* contain more stuff that should not be skipped.

And that `scanf` call looks wrong.. do you really want to enter "give me an int .." everytime?

Comment: i don't know what my teacher want. But i think that this code should be ok! ;)

Comment: Great. The next time please try solving it on your own instead of letting SO do your homework :)

Comment: This is not a real "HOmework", i'm preparing for engineering exam in C and this is a test question of the past

Answer (score 0):

Not going to give you full code, but:

- remember you can add conditions inside the clause of the `for` statement. (hint: move the breaking condition there to terminate the loop)
- does the `continue` actually do anything in your example?

Comment: continue is used to stay inside the loop until a non-negative number is entered.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, not much needs to be done. Since `a < 0` and `a == 0` are mutually exclusive conditions, an if-else-if statement could be used as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    scanf("give me and int %d", &a);

    if (a < 0)
        // Do something or nothing here, but this skips the rest of the loop
        // body just like continue would.
    else if (a == 0)
        i = N; // This satisfies the loop condition, so it won't loop again
               // just like break would.
}
```

This is not a general solution, but it should give you the proper behavior in this case.